# Document.querySelectorAll em um looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var linksMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".links-menu");

for (var i = 0; i<linksMenu.length; i++) {
    linksMenu[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
        console.log(linksMenu[i]);
    });
}
```

Não consigo mostrar a posição em que foi clicada,  no caso,  aparece como undefined.

Porém, se colocar um console.log qualquer, ele funciona exatamente na posição clicada, então está funcional.